# use CGAL to store vertices,halfedges,adjecency list of polygon

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, cgal, polyhedra

I'm creating an application using qt-creator , it's read .off files and preview it's polygon .
I want to store vertices , halfedges and adjacency list to add or remove specific vertices and storing adding and removing operations .

any help or suggested links?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Surface_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/) class is a good start.
Also the [`read_off()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/group__PkgSurface__mesh.html#gaff345ead523f3c3d2c8ec7943a9a1e6e) function might be useful.